Expected vs realized PNL from an interest rate swap
I've been looking into carry and rolldown PNL, and I'm struggling to understand how to backtest the actual carry PNL, as opposed to what is expected. I've seen some books merge carry and rolldown into one concept, so that's how I'm treating it.
Say I wanted to backtest receiving the 5y forward 1y rate every day (so every day I start a new trade). Would it be accurate to say that the PNL every day is:
Change in 5y1y swap rate everyday
If so, then why do I not need to add some measure of carry (5y1y - 4y1y)/252 everyday (but isn't that the 'expected' carry pnl, not the realized pnl)
